# HTML parsing in Clojure

Tags: html, clojure

I'm looking for a good way to parse HTML in Clojure.

Exactly what I'm trying to do is get content of a web page with crawler and then get content of some HTML tags or their attributes.

So I have URL to the page, and I get html as String, but how do get data I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use https://github.com/cgrand/enlive
It allows you to select and retrieve with CSS-alike selectors.

Or https://github.com/nathell/clj-tagsoup

I am not experienced with tag-soup but I can tell that enlive works well for most scraping.

Comment: thanks. I have already heard about enlive. Will give it a try